# File Upload error using Google Client API to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, file-upload, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

Since 2015 I have been using the Google Cloud Storage API now I have just updated the [PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) with latest version and got some error when uploading a file to google cloud storage

my error

```
{  
   "domain":"global",
   "reason":"invalid",
   "message":"Content-Type specified in the upload (application/octet-stream) does not match Content-Type specified in metadata (image/jpeg). If it was a simple upload (uploadType=media), the Content-Type was specified as a bare header. If it was a multipart upload (uploadType=multipart), then the Content-Type was specified in the second part of the multipart. If it was a resumable upload (uploadType=resumable), then the Content-Type was specified with the X-Upload-Content-Type header with the start of the resumable session. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload."
}
```

And I also Need Help for resumable upload using google client api

My code to Upload File:

```
            $storageObject->setContentType($image_type);
            $storageObject->setName($name);
            $storageObject->setSize(filesize($data["temp_name"]));
            $storageObject->setMetadata($meta_data);


            try{

                $res = $storageService->objects->insert(
                $data["bucket_name"],
                $storageObject,
                array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($data["image_temp_name"]),
                'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                'predefinedAcl'=>'publicRead'
                // 'contentEncoding'=>'gzip'
              ));
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {

                echo $e->getMessage();

            }
```

Comment: Did you change to a newer version of the API (if so from what version to what version ) or did you just update the PHP client library?

Comment: yes i changed to latest version of google client php

Comment: @DaImTo please help me for resumable upload to google cloud storage using google client php API or Any example link

Comment: Try these https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-upload.php    This is drive but its the same idea https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19

Comment: i am doing same .check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062584/resumable-upload-using-google-client-api-invalid-upload-url?noredirect=1#comment73209320_43062584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Solved it by putting mimeType In Request Params

```
        $storageObject->setContentType($image_type);
        $storageObject->setName($name);
        $storageObject->setSize(filesize($data["temp_name"]));
        $storageObject->setMetadata($meta_data);


        try{

            $res = $storageService->objects->insert(
            $data["bucket_name"],
            $storageObject,
            array(
            'mimeType' => $image_type,
            'data' => file_get_contents($data["image_temp_name"]),
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'predefinedAcl'=>'publicRead'
            // 'contentEncoding'=>'gzip'
          ));
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {

            echo $e->getMessage();

        }
```

Comment: HI Usman, I am trying to upload the file to cloud storage using the https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client And i am not able to upload the file. Please suggest me to include required files. Thanks in advance