# Resumable upload using Google Client API . Invalid Upload URL

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client, resume-upload

I am unable to perform resumable upload using this api please Help Me.This Code Working Fine Until i used resumable Upload . I can Upload FIle Using Multipart but not able upload big files with multipart

MY Code

```
            $storageObject->setName("FIle Name.mp3");
            $storageObject->setBucket($data["bucket_name"]); 
            $mimetype = mime_content_type($data["temp_name"]);

            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            $storageClient->setDefer(true);

            $status = false;

            $filetoupload = array('name' => "FIle Name.mp3", 
           'uploadType' => 'resumable');

            $request = $storageService->objects->insert(
            $data["bucket_name"], $storageObject, $filetoupload );

            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($storageClient,
            $request, $mimetype, null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);

            $media->setFileSize(filesize($data["file_temp_name"]));
            $handle = fopen($data["file_temp_name"], "rb");

            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) 
            {
               $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
               $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            $result = false;
            if($status != false) {
            $result = $status;
            }


            $storageClient->setDefer(false);
```

Response Error

```
      {
      "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
      "domain": "global",
          "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload",
       "message": "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/",
       "extendedHelp": "https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload"
      }
     ],
     "code": 400,
      "message": "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/"
      }
     }**
```

Comment: Do something with your errors! Check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#resume-upload) for more information about resuming an interrupted file upload.

Comment: there is not solution for error

Comment: Oh, I see, thought you said you can't resume an upload. Still the errors says you are uploading it the wrong way ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload)\).

Comment: This is the best example I know of for multi part. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19

Comment: multipart is working fine for me but when it comes to resumable then this error returns

Comment: can't upload big files using multipart

Answer (score 0):

Your upload url is not correct, because whenever you have to upload your files, in cloud buckets the path for Upload URL is very important. Not only on Google Cloud but even in Amazon S3 or any other cloud storage environments. These buckets create standard path for your file upload location, and make it available via CDN edges. SO it is necessary to set upload path.

For making standard HTML based file upload refer this link. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/

Comment: You are not getting my point.I am not using a customize library i am using it as it is then why this error occurs  .